# Replacing small blocks of html text in a file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I have been searching for answer for many days but I just can't solve it.
In my case I need to replace string in .htm file. String is across multiple lines, for example:

```
</table>
    <p>
<table border="1">
```

I tried the following but it isn't working and I know because the text appears over several lines.

```
Get-Content test1.htm )| ForEach{ $_ -replace '</table><p><table border="1">', "" } | Set-Content test2.htm
```

I have no idea how can I do it.

Comment: Do you want to replace always the same string? Or a pattern? Also, what do you want to replace the string with?

Comment: In this case I want to replace always the same strin, but for future it will be good to know how to manipulate. I need to remove the string or repalce with another value, so it depends.

Comment: well, you should be carefull to replace a string in a html file using the `-replace` cmdlet. You should try to use an XML parser instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: If you have been searching for a while you must have tried something. Do you have example that you have been trying we can help you with. This is a basic request with many related answers already on SO.

Comment: @Matt ( Get-Content test1.htm )| ForEach{ $_ -replace '</table><p><table border="1">', "" } | Set-Content test2.htm
But it wont work because the string is 3 lines, like:
'</table> \n
<p> \n
<table border="1">'
So I tried only with powershell.

Comment: I have included these details in the question for you. If I get a moment I can try and find a duplicate for you.

Comment: @Matt I ended with this code
 `$filenames = @("test1.htm")

foreach ($file in $filenames) 
{
    $replacementStr = ''
    (Get-Content $file | Out-String) | 
        Foreach-object { $_ -replace '</table>`r`n<p>`r`n<table border="1">' , $replacementStr   } | 
     Set-Content test2.htm
}`
but still I'm not able to replace text that appears over several lines. It works if only I want to change text that appear in **one** line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, somebody managed to solve it, so I post the answer. The cule was to include Poweshell spilt operator: **\s+**.

So my final code look like:

```
$filenames = @("test1.htm")foreach ($file in $filenames) {
$replacementStr = ''
(Get-Content $file | Out-String) | 
    Foreach-object { $_ -replace '</table>.\s+<p>\s+<table border="1">' , $replacementStr } | 
 Set-Content test2.htm }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(Get-Content 'filename').replace('toreplace', 'replacewith') | Set-Content 'filename'
```

Comment: I get the output:
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'replace'.
When I do this command there are no result
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("d:\test.xml").replace('1234','xxxx')|sc d:\test.xml /*this is only an example*/

Comment: `Get-Content -Raw ...`

Comment: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.

Comment: @lukesky `(Get-Content 'filename' | Out-String)...` would work since you have PowerShell 2.0. I think you are going to have other issues though.

Comment: @Matt
it is my current code:

(Get-Content 'test1.htm' | Out-String).replace('</table><p><table border="1">', '') | Set-Content 'test2.htm'
but it still not working.